# Is this possible to assign NSDate variable to a nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, nsdate

Suppose if i want to erase a value stored in a `NSString` variable, i will assign a `nil` to it. This is possible. But if i want to erase a date variable that already holds some values, what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nil` is just an object placeholder. You can assign any Objective-C object pointer to it.

So yeah, you can assign a variable of type `NSDate *` to `nil`.

If you have ownership of the object however, you should send it the `-release` message before setting the variable to `nil` or else the memory pointed to by the variable will be leaked.

Comment: Thank you... One more doubt. In string, we can assign an empty character to a string variable. Like NSString *s = @""; For a NSDate variable how can we assign an empty value?

Comment: @Rajkanth `[NSDate date]` would suffice.

Comment: @Rajkanth But why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a view to select Date of Birth. Suppose one may want to delete the saved birth date. So only i asked

Answer (score 3):

you can... but it is advisable to release it if it is not autorelease object..

i.e

```
[dateObject release]; // Only if it is not autorelease object.
dateObject = nil;
```

Comment: If we release a variable, it will remove from the memory. Then how can we assign a nil to it?

Comment: @Rajkanth Just because the memory is deallocated doesn't mean that the pointer reference doesn't still exist.